# html input element expand to full width

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have a simple problem but solutions I have tried does not work. I have a two column layout in my form. Furthermore, the right column is divided into two columns. Left being fixed width (label) and right being input. I'd like input and label on same line and input field fill the rest of the available space if possible. 
  Please see fiddle and let me know what I am missing.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 45%">
  <div id="keepTogether">
    <div id="label">
      Description
    </div>
    <div id="rightColumn">
      <input id="inputfield" />    
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

#keepTogether {
  height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#Label {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

#inputfield {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}

#rightColumn {
  width: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/workmonitored/4m0sj1fq/4/#&togetherjs=j3i2Q105hF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 using display flex**

**snippet**

```css
#main{
 float: left;
 width:60% ;
   display:flex;
   border:solid;
}
#keepTogether {
  border:solid;
}

#label {
  display: inline;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

#inputfield {
      -webkit-box-flex:1;
      -webkit-flex:1;
          -ms-flex:1;
              flex:1;
  
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
    <div id="label">
      Description
    </div>
      <input id="inputfield" />    
</div>
```

---

**Option 2 using table tag**

**here is a snippet**

```css
table{
  width:60%;
}
td {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
#inputfield{
  width:100%;
  margin:none;
  padding:0;

}
#label{
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr id='main'>
      <td id="label">
      Description:</td>
    <td id="rightColumn">
       <input id="inputfield" />   
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/workmonitored/4m0sj1fq/15/#&togetherjs=j3i2Q105hF I tried the sample by changing main to width 45%, it works but the input field is getting cut off due to overflow being hidden. Is there a way to make it sit on same line without input being cut off?

Comment: you can also use display flex...answer edited to show this... :D

Comment: I have used the table tag since I could not handle it any other way. None of the other solutions did work. I could not use flex since it looks like it was not supported by IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would work for you.

```
#keepTogether {
        height: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    #Label {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #inputfield {
        float: right;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #rightColumn {
        width: 80% !important;
        width: auto;
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make label fixed width?

Comment: You can give a fixed size relatively to other elements. You may be seen that the fix size will not work for some screen resolutions. So you have to test in every screen sizes. media-queries may be helpful to you. If you can use Bootstrap framework to make layout easily. It is simple and well tested.

Answer (score 0):

I found some mistake on your code. 
- Your first div is not necessary to keep. 
- Your id selection is not correct. It should be #label
And you should follow this code structure and css to fix the issue as well.

```css
#keepTogether {
  display: inline-block;
}

#label {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#inputfield {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="keepTogether">
    <div id="label">
      Description
    </div>
    <input id="inputfield" />
  </div>
```

Comment: What does you meant by left column?
If the #label is the left column, you can give it 45% width (#label: {width: 45%}) and set the width of #keepTogether to 100% (#keepTogether {width : 100%}).
See this code on https://jsfiddle.net/4m0sj1fq/16/

And you still no need the extra div for set the left column width to 45%